# Add text between affiliations and author note using APA6 package

Tags: apa6, authblk

I am working using the `apa6` package, and I would like to add the submission date on the cover page presented flush left between affiliations and author note.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,noextraspace,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk} % for double affiliations

%%% AUTHORS NAMES, AFFILIATIONS AND NOTE %%%  
\title{Title of the Study}
\shorttitle{Study} % running head
\author[1]{Author1}
\author[1]{Author2}
\author[2]{Author3}
\author[1]{Author4*}
\affil[1]{Affil1}
\affil[2]{Affil2}
\affiliation{~} % to force dual affiliation
\authornote{*Corresponding author: name@univ.fr

Funding sources: The proposed research will not receive financial support.

Conflict of interest: The authors declare no competing financial interests.

Ethics approval: The ethics committee of the University approved the study.}

%\abstract{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: FirstPage]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As always on this site please post a full (but minimal) example allowing others to test your code as is, without having to guess

Comment: Especially because you are not using the standard `apa6` methods for multiple authors, so you need to show what package you are using for that too.

Comment: I would not use `authblk` with apa6, looking in its manual, it has its own interface for multiple authors. Also: isn't the `\note{...}` (see the apa6 manual) what you are looking for?

Comment: Indeed, the `\note{}` solved my problem. Thank you so much!
Yes, it has its own interface for multiple authors, but it does not match the one I need (i.e., all the authors on the same line, and then affiliations).